# No network connection with installed version but USB version works

Tags: boot

This is my first shot at the Linux world and particularly the Ubuntu segment. I
installed Ubuntu 13.10 from a USB stick on an old Dell Inspiron 1510 and if I
boot the installed version I am unable to get a network connection, either wifi
or ethernet.

If I boot from the USB stick, the same one I used to install from, I get an ethernet connection but no wifi connection.  (Yes I do have a
working wireless network here at home.  This laptop can turn the wifi off and on
using fn - F2 but that doesn't seem to do anything, not even turn the wifi LED
on.)

I see that others have had a similar experience but was unable to find a
solution.

The results of a search on this site suggested running   `lshw -C network`   which
I did for both cases, i.e. booting the installed version and booting the USB stick version. There were several differences.  I haven't yet figured out how to capture an output stream to a text file (been a long time since I used a command
line) but the significant differences are:

Installed version:

```
network
capability: bus_master  cap_list
configuration: driver=wl latency=0
resource: irq:18
*-network unclaimed
resource irq 18


USB stick version:
*-network
capability: pm msi pciexpress bus_master   cap_list
configuration: driver=b43_pci_bridge  latency=0

ethernet section

logical name: eth0
serial:  00:19:b9:5b:60:c7
size 100 Mbits/sec
capacity: 100 Mbits/sec

capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mil 10bt 10bt_fd 100bt
100bt_fd autonegotiation


configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcasts=on driver=b44 driverversion=2.0
duplex=full ip=192.168.1.102 latency=64 link=yes multicast=yes port = twisted
pair speed=100Mbits/sec

resource: irq:21
```

It seems very strange that the same software package would configure things two
different ways.  I sure would appreciate some suggestions.

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.  No internet then go to this link for running the script without internet.
<http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385>

Answer (score 0):

Please do from your installed ubuntu:

```
sudo modprobe ssb
sudo modprobe b44
```

now ethernet should come on, then do:

```
sudo apt-get purge --remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Reboot and wireless should come on.

Comment: I tried the first line, sudo modprobe ssb and got a prompt:
[sudo] password for bob:

I entered my password and the cursor went to column one of the next line and just sits there blinking.  I waited several minutes but nothing happened.

Comment: it was waiting for you to run the second command, those two commands do not show output unless there is an error.

Comment: After running the first command, sudo modprobe ssb, not only does nothing happen, I don't even get a prompt.  I am reinstalling the system from scratch and will try again when I'm finished.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Wild Man:  The good news is that I talked with a friend who is a Debian guy and he fixed me up.  I now have ethernet and wireless access.  If it breaks I will be dead in the water!  Time to start learning more about this Linux/Ubuntu stuff.  I am a semi-retired engineer (I'm 76), and still do some contract embedded system programming.  I used to say "Real men use DOS."  I want to be able to say "Real men use the Linux command line."  :-)  Thanks for your help.  Bob